# Capture sdtout and stderr with pipe and dupe2 using C langage

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, dup

I am writing a program in C language that acts like a shell terminal, the user enters a command and I parse the line then use "execv()" to execute the command.

Now I'm trying to print the standard output and the error output with different colors (making sure that the order doesn't change. But I'm having troubles both outputs.

Thanks you for your help

```
void dumsh_execute1(char **command_args, char **redirection_args) {

  int first_pipe[2];
  int second_pipe[2];
  if( pipe(first_pipe) == -1 || pipe(second_pipe) ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
  }


  pid_t pid = fork();
  int status;
  switch (pid) {
    case -1:
      // error, failed to fork()

      break;
    case 0:
      // the child process
      close(first_pipe[0]);
      close(second_pipe[0]);
      dup2(first_pipe[1], 1);
      dup2(second_pipe[1], 2);
      close(first_pipe[1]);
      close(second_pipe[1]);

      if (execvp(command_args[0], command_args) < 0) {
        printf("Could not execute command..\n");
        exit(0);
      }

      break;
    default:
      // the parent process
      while (1) {

        fd_set rfds;
        int retval;

        /* Watch stdin (fd 0), stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) to see when it has I/O. */
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(first_pipe[0], &rfds);
        FD_SET(second_pipe[0], &rfds);

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 100000;

        retval = select( max(first_pipe[0], second_pipe[0] ) + 1, &rfds, 0, 0, &timeout);

        if (retval == -1) {
          perror("select()");
          break;
        } else if (retval) {

          if ( FD_ISSET(first_pipe[0], &rfds) ) {
            char msg[1024];
            int r = read(first_pipe[0], msg, sizeof(msg));
            if ( r < 1 ) {
              break;
            }
            printf("\033[%sm%s\033[%s", GREEN, msg, RESET);

          }
          if ( FD_ISSET(second_pipe[0], &rfds) ) {
            char msg[1024];
            int r = read(second_pipe[0], msg, sizeof(msg));
            if ( r < 1 ) {
              break;
            }
            printf("\033[%sm%s\033[%s", RED, msg, RESET);
          }
        }

      } //end while

      waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Where'd the `7` come from in your call to `select`?

Comment: Why aren't you running your `select` in a loop? Do you only want the first line of output?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica you are rightg, I just edited the code... now it works, but I am not able to terminate the while of the select. It prints everything but it doesn't end.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I fixed it, I forgot to close the pipes in the parent process. But now sometimes the output colors overlaps (a bit of stdout is in red !)

Comment: stdout and stderr are output streams.  There is no need to capture anything from them, since your process is generating the data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the assignment I have is to execute a command and print stdout and stderr with different colors as well as respecting there order ( like the command ls -R / ).